# Jquery Scroll Top Not Responding

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I have a span called `span#about`, which when I click on it, I want to scroll down the page to the top of a div called `div#perthImage`

When I click on the span, it displays 'scroll initiate' so I know that the click is being registered however it does not scroll. Can somebody please assist me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("span#about").click(function () {
      console.log('scroll initiate')
        $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('div#perthImage').offset().top }, 200);
    });
});
```

My HTML code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id='nav' class="nav"> 
    <div class='row'>
        <div class = 'col-xs-12' id = 'aboutBtn'>
            <span id = 'about'>About Us</span>
        </div>
        <div class = 'col-xs-12' id = 'citiesBtn'>
            <span id = 'cities'>Cities <i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <div id = 'oncityhover'>
                <div class = 'row' id = 'citiesDropdown'>
                    <div class = 'menuItem col-xs-12' id = 'perthScroll'>
                        Perth City
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id = 'homeLogo'>
    <center>
        <img id='logo' src="images/CulturedLogo.png">
        </div>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

        <div class = 'cities row'>
            <div class = 'locImage col-md-6' id = 'perthImage' title = 'Perth City' alt = 'Perth City'>
                <center>
                    <h4 id = 'perth'>Perth City</h4>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/0hrfx0gw/
You just missed a semicolon after your console.log call

Comment: Please provide enough code to reproduce this. What and where is `div#perthImage`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Try change your console.log line to `console.log($('div#perthImage').offset().top)` and tell me the result

Comment: It displays 545, which I understand to be correct, however still does not scroll. I have included the HTML. Also this exact method has worked on many different pages, struggling to see why it does not work on this occasion. Starting to wonder whether it is something wrong with my css??